# Is it good practice to update your question with the answer that worked?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, self-answer

If you pose a question, and someone provides an answer that works, is it a good or bad idea to update your question to show exactly what worked?

Example: [C# LINQ to SQL 2 Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042124/c-sharp-linq-to-sql-2-joins)

This user accepted an answer, but then chose to update his question to show the answer at the end of the question. To me, this feels like duplication of content, but I could see it being useful to take a general answer and expand on it with the specifics of your question.

Comment: NO! It's confusing. Let the question be the question and the answer be the answer.

Comment: Is there a source in the rules of SO that I could cite in removing this section from the question?

Comment: There's this related MSE question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111684/how-to-say-last-words-addressed-to-all-after-accepting-an-answer/111686#111686 .

Comment: thanks, I didn't find that one in my searching.

Comment: if asker wants to let others know what worked for them, this should be in the [self-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer)

Comment: I agree, I wanted to get backup before I made any suggestions or edits. Thanks all.

Comment: Even worse than adding the answer at the end of the question is IMHO when people edit the core of the question so that answers don't apply anymore. It happens with "what is wrong with this code?" type of questions, where somebody correctly points out the problem in an answer, and then the question is edited to apply the proposed solution. If somebody looks at the whole thing later, without studying the edit history, the answer doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're talking about editing your question to include what the correct answer was, then that's a bad idea.

An answer can already be found underneath the question.  It's even under a bold heading called **Answers**, so that it's really easy to identify those posts as answers.  If you're the OP there's even a green check mark that you can click on to let everyone know that it's **your** favorite answer.

There is no reason to duplicate an answer in your question's post.  It only adds more garbage to your question that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with this mentality, but I couldn't find any hard sources to back it up.

Comment: What to do if no answer was complete, but each answer contributed? Add your own answer and accept that? I feel kinda bad doing that