# How to handle someone editing their question with an answer after accepting an answer

Tags: discussion, support

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616410/subtracting-the-linkedlist-nodes) question where the OP had edited the question to include the his implementation of the accepted answer.

From [this discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258378/is-it-good-practice-to-update-your-question-with-the-answer-that-worked) and I personally feel that this practise is generally best avoided. And this edit is better placed as an separate answer to this question than an edit to the question.

I'm not sure if the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) has mentioned it explicitly on what needs to be done here (correct me if I am wrong)

So, what do you think I can do.

1. Add a comment asking the OP to add it as a seperate answer
2. Flag this as "in need for moderator intervention" and ask them to rollback to the previous version.
3. Edit and remove this "answer" section.
4. I should probaly leave it as it is